# Are there are available tools to view the entities in CoreData?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I am trying to find a way to more easily see the contents of my Core Data database. Are there any tutorials out there?

I can always write some code to go into my app to loop through all the entities, but I was wondering if there was an actual tool available to do this.

Comment: If you use the XML store you could just dump that into a UITextView and see it that way. Otherwise I never heard of anything.

Comment: Don't really know why this was closed. I found my answer. Integrating PonyDebugger does it super super well.

Answer (score 1):

You Can read directly the CoreData sqlite database file using a sqlite viewer.
There are some options for free but of very low quality.
I personally have use navicat premium.

Once you have opened the tools you need to load the sqlite db file and just navigate it.
You can access the dbfile on the Simulator finding the app working directory or on the device exporting the document application path using Xcode.

Hope this helps.